Is there a way to see when developer options were enabled?
One of my phones has had the developer options enabled and I don’t remember doing it. It’s not rooted and does not have bootloader enabled. I’m wondering if this happened when someone else had physical possession of the phone. Is it possible to check this via adb, perhaps it’s recorded in a file or the modification date of a file that can be seen via adb shell without root permission? Or perhaps another method? Android 14 / Pixel 7 Pro

Similar to: Check if developer options were active before?
